# Single users permissions on SharePoint

Tags: permissions, read

I need advice on how to manage specific folder permissions on a SharePoint site.

Users who can **edit** all will be members of the site, users who can **only read** everything will be visitors and instead, users who only need to **see/edit some folders**, how can I manage them?

Keeping in mind that **they will have to access the document root** and only **see the folders they have access to.**